# 2D graphics with C#

Tags: c#, graphics, 2d, gdi+, game-development

I see a lot of 3D graphics tech out there, but no real 2D graphics tech, nor books etc..
Any tips as to where to start for digging into 2D graphics programming in C#?

I've been fiddling with GDI+ for a while now (see demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvqPHfWCWSM).. I however want to switch to something that's faster - but for 2D: Direct2D (Dx), OpenGl, come to mind, but are they suited for 2D?

---

UPDATE 08/03/2016:
I now use [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/) a cross-platform XNA implementation.

Thanks,
Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA is a great choice because you have all the rendering power of DirectX with managed code.
If you want to use DirectX or OpenGL you have to use unmanaged C++ code (low level) which is far harder to learn/use. 
As for books there are a lot of great ones:

```
-Beginning DirecX11 Game Programming by Allen Sherrod and Wendy Jones(Course Technology)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx will check out the book. About XNA, sadly it will go without support soon..?

Comment: You could use SlimDx (http://slimdx.org). This offers about the same capabilities _plus_ support for DirectX 10 and 11 as well as 64 bit support.

Comment: ps; update, since then I use MonoGame a x-platform XNA implementation.

Answer (score 2):

For C# you always have XNA, still does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Since you obviously know how to use the GDI to render 2D graphics (impressing demo!), you should have seen that this *is* already rather fast. GDI+ uses the graphics card to support rendering, so normally you don't need anything more for 2D. Direct2D is more or less dead nowadays and one would use Direct3D also to render 2D. (DirectX 10 and later interfaces don't even have special support for 2D any more.) You would just render stuff in screen space to achieve 2D rendering.

Comment: Thx about the demo. I try to cache as much as I can (brushes, settings, pens, colors, rendered bitmaps) to increase performance on GDI+.. Can you explain why Direct2D is dead? I didn't know.. I find it a bit sad, because this means drawing 2D in 3D is a bit the other way around, grmbl :p

Comment: Hmmm... Seems I was wrong there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/hh802478(v=vs.85).aspx states that there are even new features for Direct2D in Windows 8 and 8.1. I thought it to be dead because DirectX10 did not include any interfaces for 2D support any more and Direct2D was then actually built on top of DirectX9. Seems the guys at Microsoft still found that there was an use for plain 2D support.